# `not found` error when searching for dot/dash starting files .gitignore or dash ending test-.js

Tags: node.js, github, https, get, github-api

The Goal: I am trying to search files in a repository and get its details.

I am making a github rest api request. When I make a request to any files that start with `.` say `.gitignore` or to `test/.test-template.js` OR files that end with a `-` like `test/test-.js`, it gives `not found` error with these details -
`{"message" : "NotFound", "documentation_url" : "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#get-repository-content"}`.

The request is as follows:

```
const { get } = require("https");
let username = "ganeshkbhat";
let repository = "requireurl";
let filename = "test/units/.gitignore";

get({
    hostname: "api.github.com",
    path: `/repos/${username}/${repository}/contents/${filename}`,
    headers: { "User-Agent": `${username}`, "Accept": "application/vnd.github+json", 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + `${username}:<token>` }
}, (res) => { 
      let data = '';
      res.on('data', (chunk) => data += chunk);
      res.on('end', () => resolve(data));
   }).on('error', (err) => reject(err));
```

Is there a way to search for such type of files and its details?

Answer (score 1):

I checked the repository from which you are trying to extract the **.gitignore** file, but you don't have such file under the folder **test**
And you don't have a folder named **units** that is inside **test**. So perhaps your **filename** value should be changed to just `".gitignore"`.

Comment: thank you. the file fetch works for `/repos/${username}/${repository}/contents/${filename}` now. however, the `api.github.com/search/code` search doc says the `.` will be ignored.  so what is happening is `You can't use the following wildcard characters as part of your search query: . , : ; / \ \` ' " = * ! ? # $ & + ^ | ~ < > ( ) { } [ ] @`. The search will simply ignore these symbols.` https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/searching-on-github/searching-code#search-within-a-users-or-organizations-repositories

Comment: is there a way I can use the `api.github.com/search/code` search to find files that are named `.gitignore`, `.test.template.js`, `test-.js` etc? Currently the response does not include these files. I have to run different queries based on `q=repo:xxx+user:yyy+extension:.js` etc

Comment: Hello, if you search in the docs, it's addressing the exact limitation which you are experiencing:
"You can override these default exclusions using a .gitattributes  file..." - https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/searching-on-github/finding-files-on-github

Therefore I think you can just create this file and fill it with the those kind of files. -  https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes But you have to try it out, I am not sure that this will work.

Comment: no it does not work. i got away from the issue using a `/search/code?q=extension:nn+extension:mm+extension:+ss` and so on.